# libpthread - возможна ли статическая линковка независемая от адреса (position independent) под линуксом?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, сборка, линковка

В общем, пытаюсь я собрать libtorrent под линуксом. libtorrent требует boost-python, который в свою очередь требует libpthread.  Мне необходимо сделать библиотеку статической, однако, для сборки под линукс в Jamfile прописано следующее предупреждение:

```
    linux must link dynamically against boost python because it pulls
    in libpthread, which must be linked dynamically since we're building a .so
    (the static build of libpthread is not position independent)
```

Вопрос: так ли это? Существует ли способ все же собрать библиотеку статически? И как это можно сделать?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю английский, тут `"...since we're building a .so..."` написано, что вы собираете *динамическую библиотеку* (`.so`), а не статическую `boost-python` (которую хотите собрать). Наверное надо покопаться в мейках и найти сборку `.a` (или написать ее, если отсутствует). Статическая `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a` версия в системе существует

Comment: Вот я этот момент не совсем понимаю: исключение почему-то именно для линукс, при том что я собирал libtorrent и под macos и под винду и не требовалось наличия boost.python в системе, ну или его отдельной сборки и установки, при том что библиотека сама получалась динамической (.so в macos и .pyd в винде), и я предполагаю, что динамическая билиотека статически линковалась с boost.python в таких случаях. А в линуксе мне помимо конечного приложения еще и надо будет собирать boost.python отдельно, что я и хочу исключить.